# Upgrade from 4.6.20 to 4.6.21 fails with fatal error (sqlfile not found)

Tags: upgrade, mysql

We're using D7 / Civi 4.6.20, attempted to upgrade to 4.6.21 following the Civi upgrade documentation.  The upgrade errors out with this error:

Exception: "A fatal error was triggered: sqlfile - 4.6.21.mysql not found."

I tried reloading my pre-upgrade database and repeating, but got the same error.

Backtrace:

```
#0 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php(432): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("sqlfile - 4.6.21.mysql not found.")
#1 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourSix.php(86): CRM_Upgrade_Form->processSQL("4.6.21")
#2 [internal function](): CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FourSix::task_4_6_x_runSql(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), "4.6.21")
#3 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php(88): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:2))
#4 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(214): CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
#5 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(52): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(TRUE)
#6 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(106): {closure}()
#7 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(54): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
#8 [internal function](): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#9 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): call_user_func((Array:2))
#10 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#11 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#12 SITEROOT/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(482): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#13 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("upgrade", "queue", "ajax", "runNext")
#14 SITEROOT/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:4))
#15 SITEROOT/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#16 {main}
```

I searched and couldn't find a file called 4.6.21.mysql but I did find /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/4.6.21.mysql.tpl.

Any advice?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you grab this file https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/4.6.21.mysql.tpl and then save it into same path within your civicrm dir i.e. in CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/

Once you have done that re-load your pre-upgrade database and run the upgrade again.

Should be all good then

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for the processSQL function in CRM_Upgrade_Form, I can see that it works like this:

- Given a revision (in this case, `4.6.21`), it looks for `Incremental/sql/4.6.21.mysql.tpl`.
- If that file is NOT found, it looks for `Incremental/sql/4.6.21.mysql`.
- If it finds neither, it returns the error you saw.

Here's what you can try:
* Please check the file owner/permissions of this file to ensure it can be read by your web server user.
* Ensure it's looking for the right file in the right place.  Try putting this line into `CRM/Upgrade/Form.php` at line 426:

```
CRM_Core_Error::debug_var("tplFile", $tplFile);
```

Then, on upgrade, watch your debug logs (usually at `<drupalroot>/sites/default/civicrm/ConfigAndLog`) to see the value of `tplFile`.  Please update your question if it seems to be looking for the wrong file.